# Is there any problem with using two slashes in the middle of a URL?

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the double slash mean in URLs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls)

I'm working on a mod_rewrite URL structure as follows:

```
http://example.com/search/filter1/filter2/filter3/filter4
```

There are some conditions where it is OK for the first attribute to be blank, but i want to keep the other attributes in the same position. (Otherwise I can't assume that the attribute in the second position represents what I want it to represent.) However this results in some URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/search//filter2/filter3/filter4
```

This seems to work in all browsers I've tested (Chrome,Firefox,IE9,IE compatible) and I'm not seeing any errors on the server side, so I can't think of any problems in using it. But it just looks wrong and weird to me and I'm not used to seeing it. Are there any potential downsides to using a structure that encourages URLs like this, or any major reasons no one seems to use it? (Everything I search in Google assumes I'm talking about the two slashes after `http:`)

Comment: Even though your question is different, that question and answer  cover your question so I just closed it as a dupe instead of just linking to it as an answer.

Comment: Assuming that it "is wrong", I would have said you need to check for two distinct formats of the URL... one with 4 filters and one with 3.